# How to deal with non-existing parent resources in url?

Tags: api, api-design, microservices

I've microservice, let's name it Employee. It only has employee logic, but there's a "foreign key" to the (not really) related company. There's no company resource and no company logic in this microservice.

For adding an employee, there is an endpoint like so:

`POST /companies/1/employees`

For updating an employee, there's an endpoint like so:

`PUT /companies/1/employees/1`

For selecting employees, there's an endpoint like so:

`GET /companies/1/employees`

It's all about employees and not about companies. How can I deal with this route definition, because it looks like very company related logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to look at this:

- do not treat URL paths as hierarchical resources, just as fancy names. There is no employee-company relationship that should require you to create a company before creating an employee.

  How to implement this depends on your web framework, e.g. it might be possible to simply define a route with multiple placeholders like:

  ```js
  route('/companies/:company_id/employees/:employee_id',
        (company_id, employee_id) => ...);
  ```

  rather than a kind of nested route definition.
- avoid deeply nested URLs, but give every resource type a top-level URL namespace. Here, you might choose to have `/companies/123` and `/employees/456` paths, but not a `/companies/123/employees/456` path.

  In particular, why must you use a composite (company, employee) ID, when a single, globally unique ID for the employee would likely be sufficient?